# how to run python code from jupyterlab extension

Tags: jupyter, ipython, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

https://github.com/jupyterlab/extension-template

I want to be able to run python code from this extension. how can i do that? please show me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal in Jupyter, run your Python scripts in the terminal like you would in your local terminal.
Make a notebook, and use %run  as an entry in a cell. See here. This is more full featured then using ! python  in a cell .
for more : https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-work-with-pure-python-file-py/4443

Comment: I want to be able to just run a function from js file, something like "print('hello')" and it will appear in kernel, or i want to be able to use a function that i declared in some of my python modules in the same environment like "myfunc(arg1)" by passing arg1 that is created in js. how can i achieve this?